# Can a BIOS update have solved a hardware issue?

Tags: windows-7, bios, hardware-failure

This question had gone on Serverfault, where they told me it was better suited here.

I had a Samsung laptop which recently started to make problems. It has been working flawlessly for about 4 years.

I would power it on, and after some time, usually shortly after booting, it would just freeze. Sometimes it would even fail to power on.

I took it to a repair shop, where I left it for about a week. I came back after a week and they told me that they fixed my laptop by reprogramming the BIOS. I was suspicious already but, seeing that the laptop, nicely cleaned and shiny nearly as new, seemed to be working again, I went off. They offered 2 months of warranty.

After 1 month back home, the laptop completely died. It would not power on anymore. I have a linux box which I use for my main work, this older one was running Windows and I kept it for rare moments where clients would need something Windowey. So I have used it very little in this month, and until the day it completely died, it had been working fine for the limited use I gave it.

Of course I brought it back to the repair shop. After another month (!) for them trying to repair it, they're now saying that the computer seems to have a shortcut somewhere and can't be repaired. And of course they're saying that it doesn't fit into the warranty of the first repair, as it is another type of damage.

It's not much money and I respect the work of these guys, but it's about principles.

To me, it is unlikely that the problem had been solved by the first repair. I doubt that the BIOS reprogramming would have had an effect to actually fix what seemed a hardware issue.

I want to give them the benefit of doubt and ask, from the experience of you guys here, if you see it possible that the BIOS update could have solved what seemed a severe hardware issue in the first place.

Of course that's not much information for you guys but I wonder if anything can be said. Thank you.

Comment: I'd have to assume the "shortcut" is actually "short circuit"?

Comment: It's impossible to say... possibly even without the physical machine in-hand. But, yes, the BIOS can have a significant effect on the stability and operation of a system.

Comment: The "it's impossible to say" is a major take-away for me....thanks. This will help calm me in negotiating a solution with the tech shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it seems as if the problems you were having is something that sounded similar to something they researched online and found a new(er) BIOS updated fixed that similar issue.  They applied the new BIOS and it worked correctly, so they assumed it was fixed.  They may have even opened the laptop case and cleaned out the dust and junk that accumulates, rightly believing that getting rid of this mess will help the situation.

However, it sounds like the original issue was possibly separated traces/chips on the motherboard.  This happens especially with laptops and heat can affect the situation, keeping parts from working only after the computer has time to warm up.  It's possible that after installing the new BIOS, they didn't let it heat up enough to experience the issue, hence the idea that it was fixed.

Eventually, the separated traces/chips prevent a part or the whole motherboard from working at all, which it sounds like you've hit that point.

If this was the original issue, it's unfortunate that your computer techs misdiagnosed this issue, but it happens.  I've seen 20+ year experienced techs make "the wrong call" and end up costing their customer or their company money.  Everyone has their "off days", and not all computer techs are "created equal."

Without more info, or the computer in hand to do diagnostics, we can't be sure what the real cause it, so it's all just speculation ATM.

I've seen bad BIOS versions really tear up a system, but not an already installed version slowly bring the system down over years.  I've also seen an old system regain some speed from a BIOS update, so that's not out of the question, either.

Comment: I believe this answer most closely addresses the situation. The two failure events, even with the apparent fix in between, are just too similar as too seem disconnected. I am sure the tech shop worked with the best intentions and genuinely thought to have solved the issue, but to me honestly it looks unlikely. At least, I learnt quite a bit about the impact on hardware a BIOS update can have through this conversation here. I will try to resolve the situation by showing up in person there and see what we can do. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Certain Samsung laptops have a bug in the [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) firmware (often referred to as BIOS) where the system can fail to boot if the internal firmware storage (specifically, the UEFI variable NVRAM) is more than half full. For more details, see these [blog](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html) [posts](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/23554.html) by Linux developer [Matthew Garrett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Garrett).

This bug can most easily be triggered by running Linux on these systems, but it isn't limited to Linux. I'm not surprised that reflashing the firmware fixed the issue.

Here's another post on Super User about this issue: [Cannot access BIOS after installing a Linux distro](https://superuser.com/questions/867761/cannot-access-bios-after-installing-a-linux-distro)

Comment: Thank you, this teaches me about the impact of BIOS to hardware...Nonetheless, the guy in the last link you post was able to use his computer - just not access the BIOS. Quite different to my case.