# BIOS only able to boot to single linux installation, unable to access setup

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub, kali-linux

Recently, I installed Kali Linux on an older laptop of mine (Samsung NP0027C S01US). Today, I tried to boot from a flash drive, and it did not work. I tried to access my BIOS (F2 key), and it did not work (before people tell me to try the F keys, I have tried them already). Every time the computer booted, it would go right to the grub loader:[image: Grub loader]

Previously when I have been unable to access the BIOS, I removed my hard drive. So I pulled out the hard drive and now the computer does not boot or go to the BIOS. It starts up and shows me a boot menu:[image: Boot menu]

How does it know that Kali is a boot option with no disk present? I have been working with computers for years and this is the first time I have ever seen an issue like this. It is like linux has locked down my computer to only work with this installation. The future implications of this are a serious problem.

I have tried inserting both a bootable USB and a bootable CD and the boot menu does not show either of them. They used to work when I had Windows installed on here.

Also, there is nothing underneath the App Menu shown in the photo.

Any suggestions? I want my old boot options back and I especially want to be able to access BIOS.

EDIT 3/7/19: I have used the BIOS on this particular laptop many times in the past. I know the keyboard combinations are F2 for BIOS/setup and F11 for boot menu. Just for the heck of it I tried some other ones, but no success. Its as if my BIOS is in a fast boot mode where it ignores user input before boot (but again, normally to fix this problem in the past, I just pull the HDD).

Another interesting observation: my change brightness key is F2. When I hold Fn-F2, it will change the brightness while inside an OS. This time, however, it changed the brightness during my samsung splash screen. Is this helpful information? I don't recall if I was ever able to do this before.

(also changed title from " Linux does not allow me to boot from any other device" to more accurately reflect my issue based on comments)

EDIT 3/9/19: I reset CMOS today, thinking that it would correct any BIOS issues. Now it still does  not work and the "Kali" boot option has disappeared. It will not even boot when I have the working hard drive installed. It shows the boot menu with 0 listings. As of now, the computer is a brick. Looks like my issue is related to this question: [Cannot access BIOS after installing a Linux distro](https://superuser.com/questions/867761/cannot-access-bios-after-installing-a-linux-distro)

They have fixes if you can still boot, but I cannot. Any recommendations?

Comment: Shouldn't have anything to do with Linux, Windows, flash drives, etc. The bios is the motherboard and there's always an opportunity to reach the bios should you do so during the window except for when the hardware has a problem that it can't. It can't get to grub before the bios. How about holding down the enter bios key immediately after power on? Does that not work?

Comment: Have you tried tapping Insert when starting or Delete? Those are common alternatives to fn keys. Also, this us not a Linux problem, but might be UEFI related.